# Paid Video Streaming iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video-streaming, vimeo

I am about to build an app that initially displays thumbnails of my Vimeo Video channel. When  users click on a thumbnail, they will go through iOS's in-app payment system to pay for the video and once that is complete, the video will open and start playing in Quicktime( iphones native video player).

From my description of the app, do you see anything that may not be possible or may not be allowed by apple?

Do you think I can have half an hour videos on vimeo and display them on my app?

I would also like to include a section for magazines. What is the best way to display magazines? Just include a regaulr pdf document and let the iphone open it when clicked?

Comment: You should check out the App Store review guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple questions. Playing a video is not difficult. To protect the contents, study DRM.

For magazine, there is a subscription model for in-app purchase. Users can renew their subscription automatically/ manually.

Comment: Sorry about the multiple questions. My main concern is , will such an app be rejected by apple under any grounds. Apple have been known to restrict apps for ridiculous reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the apple inapp purchase api, that part should be fine, if you go outside that then they will reject. In other words Apple wants their percentage on the purchase.

if the Vimeo channel is using http streaming protocols per apple guidelines, or is h264 progressive download, then again you should be fine. otherwise your ok over wi-fi but much more restricted over cellular .

Answer (score 0):

This would be against our (Vimeo) Terms of Service unless you had a PRO account. Besides that, there is no API access to the external URLs yet, so that may impact what you had in mind. They will be available soon though.

Comment: Thanks, can you please refer me to where similar idea may have been applied? i.e vimeo videos are streamed and made available over an app.